# Angular Material 6 date picker is not being converted in PHP to Y-m-d format

Tags: php, angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I have this angular material date picker:

```
<mat-form-field color="warn">
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="add_date" placeholder="Date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>&nbsp;
```

This value is not readable with MysQL as is not the required format `Y-m-d`, so I convert the date sent to PHP like the following:

```
$dateAdded = strtotime('y-m-d', $dateAdded);
$dateAdded = date('Y-m-d', $dateAdded);
```

And everything added to database now is having the date of: `Jan 1, 1970`.

The format sent from Angular is like:

> date: Fri Sep 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the format of the date you do like this

```
$dateRequired=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($your_date));
```

In ts file you can add this code to get the date in the correct format

```
let d=new Date(date value);
let actualDate=d.getDate();
let actualMonth=d.getMonth()+1;
let actualYear=d.getFullYear();    
let formattedDate=actualDate + '/' + actualMonth + '/' + actualYear;
```

Comment: Nope. It is the same `Jan 1, 1970`. I think it should be fixed from angular side. The actual date sent to PHP is like: `date: Fri Sep 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)`

Comment: can you show us the `console.log()` result and the result you get the backend `print_r()`

Comment: print_r giving `2018-00-13` where no month is shown

Comment: console.log is giving `Fri Sep 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)`

Comment: console the whole form data please

Comment: Check the image I've added in the question

Comment: not the form data you are sending in request. form data you get when you submit the form `console.log('formname')`

Comment: Check the new image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180044/discussion-between-exterminator-and-droidnation).

Comment: Read the documentation once as well [Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings)

Comment: It worked. But is it good to use plain java script with angular ?

Comment: yes and basically typescript is the superset of javascript. some of the javascript functions are available in typescript as well, so there is no issue.

Comment: Can I ask you a question ? If I am building an application with angular and PHP, can I host it locally and let several users have access to it locally ? So I will put the build files and server script files on wamp, and configuring apache to accept connection from specific IPs ? Or Angular is made just for online apps? If yes, we will stop working because we don't have the capability to put it online

Comment: I have no idea about it. If it is possible or not.